# Foundation 6 with angular 6 integration not working

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to use some of the components of foundation such as model and accordion menu but unfortunately this is not working.

```
    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItems } from '../../shared/menu-items';
import { Foundation } from 'node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core';
declare var $:any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  isShrinkMedium: Boolean = true
  menuItems;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    Foundation.addToJquery($);
    $(document).foundation();
    this.menuItems =  new MenuItems().getAll();
   }
```

This is my component.I receive the folowing errors in the console.

[image]

And when I click on where I have circled in the picture I get this below.

[image]

Due to this nothing of the foundation components are working, but everything was wroking fine wehen I was using a lower version, version 4. Hope someone has an idea of what is going on here

Comment: `npm i  --save @types/jquery`

Comment: Vikas I have already done that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cd path_project

npm install jquery
npm install foundation-sites

npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/foundation-sites --save-dev
```

if not working!

---

copy this

```
 interface JQuery {
     foundation(method?: string | Array<any>, ...args: any[]): JQuery;
  }
```

from

/path_project/node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.d.ts

and paste it in

/path_project/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts

set it in the last line

---

in

/path_project/src/polyfills.ts

set ===>

```
    /***************************************************************************************************
 * JQuery
 */
import 'jquery';
```

---

now in your code you can set

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// import 'jquery'; // set this in polyfills.ts
//// import * as $ from 'jquery';
// import { Foundation } from 'foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'ex4';
  ngOnInit() {
      // Foundation.addToJquery($);
    $(document).foundation();
  }
}
```

---

Don't forget

add "css" and "js" to

/path_project/angular.json

like this

```
   "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js"
    ]
```

---

restart

```
ctr+c


ng serve
```